# Cisco - MtR alternatives

Tags: latency, cisco-ios, mtr

I trying to establish if there is a function within IOS somewhere that can provide the same results of MTR , i know it can be run from Juniper devices / *Nix & Windows devices.

Goal is to troubleshoot intermittent voice packet loss , potentially due to latency somewhere in the network.

MTR summary: probes routers on the route path by limiting the number of hops individual packets may traverse, and listening to responses of their expiry. It will regularly repeat this process, usually once per second, and keep track of the response times of the hops along the path.

[image: MTR example from a unix host]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use IP SLA set up to send udp packets of the appropriate size / codec / etc.  This can provide you back tons of information on the quality of your network, MOS score, etc.  This is a reasonable article describing one way of setting up IP SLA feature that is relevant to voice diagnostics:

http://www.networkworld.com/community/node/30924

A second alternative would be to leverage Cisco Medianet capabilities built in to a number of routers, switches, etc.  Medianet provides a ton of diagnostic information including the ability to run simulations and introduce load directly from your network devices to diagnose real-time communications problems (voice, video, etc).  It also offers the capability you're describing to do hop-by-hop mapping to quickly determine where in a path loss is occurring.

Start here to begin learning about Medianet:

http://www.cisco.com/web/solutions/medianet/knowledgebase/index.html

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried "traceroute" command on Cisco IOS.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/iosswrel/ps1831/products_tech_note09186a00800a6057.shtml#traceroute

Comment: You guys, are so mean with this user; traceroute for sure is not 100% mtr, still two negative votes. Not nice!