# mtr-like tcl script for Cisco devices

Tags: mtr

I was wondering if anyone has made an [mtr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTR_(software))-like tcl script for Cisco devices to get a "remote" picture, or if there is a good reason to not make/use it.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the edit @teun-vink - I edit so much in mediawiki markup that it leaked :-)

Comment: [This question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/cisco-mtr-alternatives) asked for something similar, but not in tcl per-se.